# Image doesnt show even though its URL is correct

Tags: image, png

I'm just working on a HTML doc (no other language).
The image URL is 100% correct. No 404 error message in console.

If you enter the img URL, this is what you see, some 20x20 px empty square.

[image]

I've already checked my directory and file permissions in FileZilla. 
What could it be?

Comment: it's probably not a valid png file.  have you tried downloading it and opening it?

Comment: Of course. Its not one damaged file, and it happens to every png or jpg file.

Comment: i downloaded the file shown above and it's damaged.  how are you creating/viewing the files, and how are you uploading the files?

Comment: if you are using ftp, make sure that you are using binary transfer mode.

Comment: Thanks very much @jdigital ! Problem solved using binary transfer mode.